# Can't use dir function with string variable and (*) sign

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use the dir function with (*) sign in order to auto-complete a partial pathname (In this example: **Deskt -> Desktop)**
This is the code I tried, but it says I got a syntax error:

```
Sub check()
    Dim folderpath As String
    folderpath = "C:\Users\levs\Deskt"
    MsgBox (Dir(folderpath*, vbDirectory))
End Sub
```

However, if I write the code without using the variable, it will work:

```
MsgBox (Dir("C:\Users\levs\Deskt*", vbdirectory)
```

So is it possible to use a variable with this function?

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 1):

You need to further build up the string:

```
MsgBox (Dir(folderpath & "*", vbDirectory))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more a syntax than another thing...

if you do 
`folderpath = "myPath"` then the variable **folderpath** is a String, now if you do something like **folderpath***, then you are using an unary operator to a variable that holds a string...

Take in consideration that this is totally different operation to concatenating the string with "*"...()
in some languages can be a multiply operator, but in others something more complex like a pointer...

## Solution:

Do the concatenation properly, i.e replace 
`MsgBox (Dir(folderpath*, vbDirectory))`  for

```
MsgBox (Dir(folderpath&"*", vbDirectory))
```

or event better do the concatenation in the declaration...

your final method should look like:

```
Sub check()
Dim folderpath As String
   folderpath = "C:\Users\levs\Deskt*"
   MsgBox (Dir(folderpath, vbDirectory))
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you elaborate please?

Comment: @Lev I have a typo with the concatenation sign... replace the + with &

Answer (score 0):

your need to concatenate widlcard and your folder path

```
sub check()
    Dim folderpath As String
    folderpath = "C:\Users\levs\Deskt"
    MsgBox (Dir(folderpath & "*", vbDirectory))
End Sub
```